# Q: How to expand the text blank in pdf?

Tags: java, python, pdf

Is there a way that I can edit the content in pdf and expand the text blank according to the length of the content ?

It seems that pypdf2 can only merge two pdf instead of changing the original one.

Itext can edit pdf based on the "text zone" attribute, but I can just use the position of the text blank in pdf and merge the text directly.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot.

---

Update 4.27
My code is:

```py
def createmark(marks):
    width = letter[0]
    height = letter[1]
    markpdf = "mark.pdf"
    c = canvas.Canvas(markpdf, pagesize=letter)
    c.translate(0, height)
    #reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics.registerFont(reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFont('guofu', os.path.join(DataDir, 'font.ttf')))
    for mark in marks:
        text = str(mark["text"])
        bounding = mark["boundingBoxes"][0]
        leftx = bounding[0] * width
        leftupy = bounding[1] * height
        leftdowny = bounding[-1] * height
        gap = leftdowny - leftupy
        fontsize = random.uniform(gap / 3, gap / 2)
        #c.setFont('guofu', fontsize)
        position = random.uniform(leftupy, leftdowny + gap / 4) 
        #c.drawString(leftx, -leftdowny + gap / 2, text)
        c.drawString(leftx, -position, text)
        c.setFillAlpha(1)
    c.save()


def genpdf(inpdf, markpdf, outpdf):
    pdf_output = PdfFileWriter()
    input_stream = open(inpdf, 'rb')
    pdf_input = PdfFileReader(input_stream, strict=False)
    pdf_watermark = PdfFileReader(open(markpdf, 'rb'), strict=False)
    page = pdf_input.getPage(0)
    page.mergePage(pdf_watermark.getPage(0))
    page.compressContentStreams()  
    pdf_output.addPage(page)
    pdf_output.write(open(outpdf, 'wb'))
```

If I want to use "pypdf2" to add some text to a pdf, I have to create a "mark.pdf" which contains the text I want to add first. And then I merge the two pdf into one.

In some forms，we have to fill the blank, such as name, age, etc. But if I just merge the "mark.pdf" with the form, I can't change the blank looks like which means, if the name is too long, the text will be out of the name blank.

I tried to use the Itext in java which can provide this function. But It requires that the text blank has have a "text zone" attribute when generate a pdf. And the form pdf(provided by clients) I use may not have this attribute.

So I was wondering that is there a way I can use to change the length and width of the text blanks to fit the text I want to add.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "text blank" and the length of what content?

Comment: And what is that "text zone" attribute?

Comment: I updated my description. Can you help me solve my problem? Thanks a lot.